# Запрос к БД MS SQL. Максимум без Max

Tags: sql, sql-server

Нужно придумать как написать запрос без использования Max, который вернул бы имена **всех** сотрудников с максимальным окладом.

> Структура таблицы:
>
> **tbl_Employee**
>
> - Id(int)
> - Name(nvarchar250)
> - Id_Department(int)
> - Salary(int)

```
SELECT Name
FROM tbl_Employee
WHERE Salary --как же обойтись без Max?
```

Comment: На какое то учебное задание похоже. вы что нибудь пробовали сделать сами ? И меня потом не заминусуют за ответ на вопрос с sql-ex например ?

Answer (score 4):

```
select Name from(
  select Name,rank() over(order by Salary desc) N
    from tbl_Employee
) A where N=1
```

Ну и в конце концов в условиях задачи ничего не сказано про `min`, а зарплаты не бывают отрицательными:

```
select Name from tbl_Employee
 where Salary=(select -min(-Salary) from tbl_Employee)
```

хотя это скорее шутка, но вполне рабочая :)

Comment: Блин, я до -MIN не додумался :'(.

Comment: @Mirdin  Ну в реальной системе я бы так не написал, min(-Salary) ни один оптимизатор не додумается брать из индекса, если он есть и полный перебор гарантирован.

Comment: Так это и не реальная база, интервью при приеме или олимпиада, что то такое... с извратом

Answer (score 1):

Мне приходит в голову только вложенным запросом, что в принципе не есть гуд

```
SELECT Name FROM tbl_Employee
WHERE Salary = 
    (SELECT TOP 1 Salary FROM tbl_EMmployee 
     ORDER BY Salary DESC)
```

Наверное кто то даст ответ лучше

Comment: TOP 1 ограничивает вывод одной записью, как я понимаю. А что на случай нескольких сотрудников получающих равную, максимальную оплату труда?

Comment: @DenisOleshchenko, TOP 1 в данном случае использовано в подзапросе, что бы получить размер максимальной з/п. А внешний запрос выведет вам всех сотрудников с данной з/п

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Name
FROM tbl_Employee
WHERE Salary >= ALL(SELECT isnull(salary,0) FROM tbl_Employee)
```